# Checking HTTP Status code without cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, swift, http-status-code-404

I need to check if a website is reachable before loading it.  I am new in iOS developement but this is the method I've implemented to discover the response.

```
   var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")

    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        data, response, error in

        println(data)

        var httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse

        println(httpResponse)
    }
    task.resume()
```

It works! But the problem is that the response comes from the cache... So the result is that:
If I am checking if a file exists and at that moment I am checking it exists -> for the application it will always exist because it is stored in the cache... So if I remove the file and then I make the request... it will always give me response 200 and not 404.

Infact if I insert this line of code (it deletes the cache!) before making the request then it works like it should work and it always check for real if the website or the file exists!

```
 NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

So... how can I solve this problem in Swift?...thank you very much

Comment: Have you looked at Apple's Reachability sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a no cache policy by using a new url session instance.

Create a property and set a new NSURLSession instance to it.

```
var urlSession : NSURLSession!

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
self.urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
```

Use this URLSession property to get your data.

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")

var task =  self.urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
      data, response, error in
            // Your code
}
task.resume()
```